# How to Delete a directory from Hadoop cluster which is having comma(,) in its name?

Tags: file, hadoop

I have uploaded a Directory to hadoop cluster that is having "," in its name
like "MyDir, Name" when I am trying to delete this Directory by using rmr hadoop shell command
as following

```
hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://host:port/Navi/MyDir, Name
```

I'm getting the following messages
rmr: cannot remove hdfs://host:port/Navi/MyDir,: No such file or directory.
rmr: cannot remove Name: No such file or directory.

However I have successfully deleted other Directories from the same location, using the same command
i.e.

```
hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://host:port/dir_path
```

any solutions to delete such kind of Directories.

Comment: It's not the comma, it's the space character beind it. Placing your argument inside quotes will help.

Comment: yes @rsp there was space too after comma, i have used the following command to delete this directory successfully "hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://host:port/Navi/MyDir\,\ Name"  it works.

Comment: The `\` in the command line escape the comma (unnecessary) and the space. Using quotes will escape any character needed, both will work.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Have you tried :

`hadoop dfs -rmr hdfs://host:port/Navi/MyDir\,\ Name`?

Comment: this is deprecated it should be " hadoop fs -rm -r <directory> "

Comment: or shorter `hdfs dfs -rm -r <directory>`

Answer (score 78):

Or if you dont know the url, you can use

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -f /user/the/path/to/your/dir
```

Comment: do you mean hadoop fs -rmr -f /user/the/path/to/your/dir?

Comment: "-rmr" is deprecated in Hadoop 2.6. The answer stating "-rm -r" is alright.

Answer (score 24):

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 9):

Run the command in the terminal

```
$hadoop fs -rm -r /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 5):

In hadoop1.0:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /PATH/ON/HDFS
```

In hadoop2.0:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R /PATH/ON/HDFS
```

Use `\` to escape `,` in path

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html) you can find all hadoop shell commands:

**deleting**:
rmr
Usage: `hadoop fs -rmr URI [URI …]`

Recursive version of delete.

Example:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/hadoop/dir
hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://nn.example.com/user/hadoop/dir
```

Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

Answer (score 2):

Try `hadoop dfs -rm -r hdfs://host:port/Navi/MyDir\,\ Name` now

Answer (score 1):

```
$ hadoop fs -rmdir {directory_name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can: 
`hadoop fs -rm -r PATH`

Hint: if you enter: 
`hadoop fs -rmr PATH`
you would mostly get:Please use 'rm -r' instead.